# Issue Placing User Generated Data into path for JSON Data in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get a changeable file link to work. It should be able to take in two variables and place them into a link to fetch some sentence out of a JSON file.

I've tried converting them to a string, which didn't work. When I hard coded the path, it worked, but I want it to be changeable on the fly.

```
//json parsing code
const url = 'storyline.json';
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(url);  
let storylineJSON = JSON.parse(rawdata);
//Json code (saved as storyline.json in different file in the same folder).
{
    "tigers":{
        "option1":"The tiger is the largest species among the Felidae and classified in the genus Panthera"
        "option2":"It is most recognizable for its dark vertical stripes on reddish-orange fur with a lighter underside"
    }
}

let optionValue = 'option1';
let startingWord = 'tigers';
let placement = String(startingWord.optionValue);

//used to read out to ALEXA


const speechText = storylineJSON.placement;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
```

The expected result is Alexa to read off the message placed in the json file. If I hard code the path into the path rather than getting user generated data, it works perfectly, but I need it to be able to switch between at the call of the user.

When I try this, it works, but states "undefined". If I place extra text around it, for example, "you just chose, " and then add the variable, it will return "you just chose undefined". I believe this to be a formatting problem that I don't know about Node.JS.

Comment: You dont need to read the json from a `fs` function you just can use `const json = require('storyline');`. Now you can access it with `json.tigers.option1`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

The issue was with how I joined all the parts of the path. For variables, I have to wrap them in [], rather than just a simple `.`.